# Getting NullPointerException Using Robolectric to Unit Test Android Activity

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I am developing an Android app with several Activity classes.  I am using Robolectric for unit testing.  In the test setup I call onCreate(null) in the Activity being tested:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity = new StartARound();
    activity.onCreate(null);
    btnSelectCourse = (Button) activity.findViewById(com.catalyst.golfapp.R.id.btnSelectCourse);
    btnAddACourse = (Button) activity.findViewById(com.catalyst.golfapp.R.id.btnAddACourse);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) activity.findViewById(com.catalyst.golfapp.R.id.btnShowLocation);
    textView1 = (TextView) activity.findViewById(com.catalyst.golfapp.R.id.textView1);
}
```

The problem is, the onCreate method for the Activity I'm testing calls:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Execution of this line of code produces a java.lang.NullPointerException error and the tests do not run.  Any ideas, or additional code you'd like to examine?

Answer (score 0):

`getActionBar()` isn't implemented in the latest version of Robolectric.

This is the source file for the ShadowActivity:
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowActivity.java

This API can be used to see when you're using a function that doesn't exist in robolectric:
http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/Robolectric.html#logMissingInvokedShadowMethods()

Answer (score 0):

Btw, using `getActionBar()` is not recommended. Instead use Android-AppCompat-v7 which includes the newer action bar. You can get it using `getSupportActionBar()`